# custom validation for date

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a custom validation which evaluates if the date requested for creating a record is available.

this is my table schedule schema

```
  create_table "schedules", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "doctor_id"
    t.boolean  "sun"
    t.boolean  "mon"
    t.boolean  "tue"
    t.boolean  "wed"
    t.boolean  "thu"
    t.boolean  "fri"
    t.boolean  "sat"
  end
```

e.g. If the date requested is friday and `schedule.fri` is true the record can be created else raise an error.

Is there a way to iterate through the data fields of the table schedule to evaluate which days return true or false so I can compare it with the requested day?

Comment: Are you doing a validation on a ````Schedule```` model or on a different model that needs to compare against ````Schedule````. From the description, it sounds like you might have another model (e.g. ````Appointment````) that you're trying to validate against this model?

Comment: that is right @GSP, is on a different model called Appointment, this object has a property called adate from which Im suppose to extract the day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this. Assuming you're trying to validate an `Appointment` model the validation might look something like:

```
class Appointment
  # this assumes that the appointment has at least two fields:
  # doctor_id : the same value as in the Schedule object
  # adate : a string in the form "mon", "tue", etc.
  validate :doctor_is_free
  def doctor_is_free 
    schedule = Schedule.where(doctor_id: self.doctor_id).first
    #return the day of a date. e.g. "sun"
    requested_day = adate.to_date.strftime("%a").downcase

    # this line will send a request to the Schedule instance using
    # the value of adate as the method name. So if adate == 'tue' and
    # schedule.tue = false then this will add an error to the validation.
    unless schedule.send(requested_day.to_sym)
      self.errors[:adate] << "The doctor is not available on #{ self.adate }"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using 'requested_day = adate.to_date.strftime("%a").downcase' to get the "day". when I test it in the console it returns the day but when I implement it I get 'undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass'. - @GSP

Comment: That would mean that the value of ````adate```` hasn't been set at the time when that line of code is run. When you're trying this is ````adate```` being set through a form, through a test or working directly in the console?

Comment: Working directly on the console. - @GSP. However if I set the value in the form for adate then I get 'undefined method `requested_day'. - @GSP

Comment: I would guess that's two different issues. When in the console, if you create your appointment like ````appt = Appointment.build(adate: Date.today)```` then the line your wrote should work something like ````requested_day = appt.adate.strftime('%a')````.  If you're seeing and undefined method 'requested_day' in a form, that would imply that the form is looking for a 'requested_day' rather than your 'adate' field.

Comment: BTW, what type of data is ````adate````? If it's stored in teh database as a ````DateTime```` you probably don't need to call to_date on it? The strftime will work on any of the ````Time```` subclasses, i think.

Comment: is a date data type. @GSP. are you online? so we can start a brief chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23384/discussion-between-evanx-and-gsp)